# How to add max value in Progressbar with label(textbox) in C#?

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, label

I want to add a maximum value to the progressbar with the label(textbox).

Comment: Yes, i update my question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am create a simple project for you look image for sample code.

- Add a timer for update values.And click timer one time set start with
  application true
- And add two label.(Sample: label1 is progressbar value / label 2 is progressbar max. value)
- And add a button for set progressbar max value.

Code sample:

```
button1 click event:

progressBar1.Maximum = Int32.Parse(textBox1.value);

timer event: (don't forget set start true with application)

progressBar1.Increment(2); //Loading progressbar

label1.value = Convert.ToString(progressBar1.Value);

label2.value = Convert.ToString(progressBar1.Maximum);
```

And a image from sample project:

[image: Did you mean that?]

label3 is showing your progressBar max value with timer updating every 1ms.

label5 is showing your progressBar value.

Comment: Please add code, errors and data as **text** ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). In general, code/errors/data in text format >>>> code/errors/data as an image >> nothing.  Images should only be used, *in addition to text in code format*, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: In this case, what's desired by the question is something visual. Having an image, which demonstrates what the code produces, is nice. So, it's reasonable to have an image, but only *in addition to having the code as text (in code format)*, not as the only thing showing the code.